# GoogleApiClient has an optional Plus.API and is not connected to Plus with new Google sign introduced in Play Services 8.3

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm getting lots of reports of my app crashing when trying to use Plus' People Api to access user's basic profile information.

Here's my setup of GoogleApiClient

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                    .requestIdToken(<id_token>)
                    .requestProfile()
                    .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .build();
```

Getting a IllegalStateException on this line:

```
Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClientPlus)
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient has an optional Plus.API and is not connected to Plus. Use GoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API) to guard this call.

This code only gets called after google sign in returns with a signed in user. So why isn't the plus api connected?

Answer (score 5):

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile.
    // ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    gGoogleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API
    // and the options specified by gGoogleSignInOptions.
    gGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGoogleSignInOptions)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
}


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Google+
            if (gGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API))
                Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(gGoogleApiClient);
            else
                Log.e("TAG", "Google+ not connected");

            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else 
            Log.e("TAG", "Result Cancelled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following instead (of course, make sure your Google's account has Google+ profile already):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();


mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();
```

Please take a look at [my sample project at GitHub](https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo). Hope it helps!

Comment: You're requesting a Plus Login Scope, but doesn't that gets handled automatically when you add Plus Api to the Google API Client?

Comment: Pls read https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes.html#PLUS_LOGIN

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I added that scope to gso. However, it's still crashing with the same exception when logging in for the first time, when user is asked about the permissions in the login flow. I disconnect the app and try again, it works and doesn't show me the permission dialog. But it should show the permission dialog, like it's the first time login. So, the app isn't disconnecting and I'm unable to test again. Any tips here?

Comment: make sure your Google's account has Google+ profile already. `with the same exception when logging in for the first time` what is the exception? One more thing, perhaps you should remove that Google account from your phone, then use your app to re-add

Comment: Yes, my account has a g+ profile. By same exception, I meant IllegalStateException that's mentioned in the question.

Comment: As in my GitHub project you can check `if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API)) {`. And try removing that Google account from your phone (Settings-Accounts...), then use your app to re-add

Comment: Yes, my question was why do I have to check this. Since Plus api is already added and onConnected is called and is handled by play services, why isn't the Plus API already connected?

Comment: I see, according to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client, we only need to check that if we use `addApiIfAvailable()`. However, they said `If you call addApi() and the GoogleApiClient is unable to connect successfully to that API, the entire connection operation for that client fails and triggers the onConnectionFailed() callback.`. Moreover, you can try as their guide `To find out why a particular API failed to connect when the entire connection operation succeeded for the client, call getConnectionResult() and get the error code from the ConnectionResult object.`

Comment: However, have you tried `hasConnectedApi` yet and it returned true or false?

Comment: I have just tried remove `.requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)) `, it's still working. I think if this request set and Google account does not have Google+ profile yet, "G+ Create a profile" will be displayed. And `if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API))` just to make sure the app does not crash. IMO, you can check your Google+ profile settings more

Comment: If `.requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))` used and you DENY access when dialogs displayed, then `mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API)` return FALSE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98658/discussion-between-droidster-and-bnk).

Comment: Was the problem solve ? I have the same issue, same code and can't find solution on the web.